# C - Errors when trying to make a hashtable

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I'm working on a hash table that stores strings in linked lists so I can avoid collisions. However, I'm getting two errors that I'm not sure how to fix. The first error I am getting is in the line that says `NewT->Table[i] == NULL;`. It's saying `warning: statement with no effects [-Wunused-value]`.

The second error I'm getting is in the same function. The error is in the line `return NewT` and the error is `warning: return from incompatible pointer type[enabled by default]`. I've been staring at this for awhile and I can't see where there is an unused value and I have no idea what the return error means even after a bit of research. Can someone explain these to me and help me fix them?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599

/*Structures*/
typedef struct List_T 
{
    char *str;
    int count;
    struct List_T *next;
} ListT;

typedef struct Hash_T
{
    int htsize;
    ListT **Table;
} HashT;

/*Prototypes*/
unsigned int hash(const char *str);
HashT **ht_create(void);

int htsize;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Please declare a table size");
        return 1;
    }
    htsize = atoi(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
unsigned int hash(const char *str)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int h = 0U;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        h = h * HASH_MULTIPLIER + (unsigned char) str[i];

    return h % htsize;
}

HashT **ht_create(void)
{
    HashT *NewT;
    int i;

    if (htsize < 1) //invalid size for
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid Size for table");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((NewT = malloc(sizeof(HashT))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid size for table");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((NewT->Table = malloc(sizeof(ListT *) * htsize)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid size for table");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<htsize; i++)
    {
        NewT->Table[i] == NULL;
    }

    NewT->htsize = htsize;

    return NewT;
}
```

Comment: Drop one = in the assignment. You are returning NewT, however the return in the function definition indicates it should be a pointer to a pointer, my c is a little rusty but I think it should be returning &NewT or change the signature to only use a single *.

Comment: @aggaton: You're correct, though you could've just given me your vote --shameless advertising indeed :D

Comment: Sorry when I snagged the question from the list I thought I was the only one answering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first error I am getting is in the line that says `NewT->Table[i]
>   == NULL;`. It's saying `warning: statement with no effects [-Wunused-value]`.

This error shows up because the code is making a *comparison* and not an *assignment*. The value returned by the comparison (is `Table[i]` null?) is itself not assigned to anything else, which means it's unused.

Keep a single `=` operator instead of the doubled `==` to make sure you're actually assigning instead of comparing.

> The second error I'm getting is in the same function. The error is in
>   the line return NewT and the error is warning: return from
>   incompatible pointer type[enabled by default].

Your function claims to be returning a pointer to a pointer to `HashT`, or `HashT **`, but you end up returning a pointer to `HashT`, or `HashT *` instead, which is the type of your `NewT` variable.

Your function's signature should use a single `*` instead of two.

Comment: when I change the function signature to a single `*` I get an error saying `error: conflicting types for 'ht_create'`. Any other tips? I tried what the other user suggested by making the return statement `return &NewT;` but got an error there too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @donutjuice: Then you seem to have other problems. I just tried the change by removing a single `*` from both the forward declaration *and* the function definition and it built without errors for me. (I had only read the code earlier, not tried it.)